# Remove entries from one CSV file that are already present in another

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv-simple

I have two files: 'file1' has employee ID numbers, 'file2' has the complete database of the employees. Here is what they look like:

- `file1`

  ```
  123123
  222333
  ```
- `file2`

  ```
  111222 Jones Sally
  111333 Johnson Roger
  123123 Doe John
  444555 Richardson George
  222333 Smith Jane
  223456 Alexander Philip
  ```

I want to compare the two files and eliminate the entries from `file2` that have ID numbers in `file1`.

I found this `awk` command which works perfectly:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};!($1 in a)' file1 file2 > file3
```

The result:

- `file3`

  ```
  111222 Jones Sally
  111333 Johnson Roger
  444555 Richardson George
  223456 Alexander Philip
  ```

So this works as expected.

*My problem is* that the files are actually simplified `.csv` files, and I must use a comma as a separator rather than a space.  I have tried everything I can think of to make this work (i.e `-F,` , `-F','` , `-F","`  everywhere in the command) and no success.

How do I get this to work with `.csv` files?

By the way, I am on MacBook Pro,  OSX Lion!

Comment: Did you have a space after `-F`?

Comment: Do you want commas in the input or output, or both?

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming your `csv` files are something like:

### File1

```
123123,,
222333,,
```

### File2

```
111222,Jones,Sally
111333,Johnson,Roger
123123,Doe,John
444555,Richardson,George
222333,Smith,Jane
223456,Alexander,Philip
```

You could try using the `join` command, like so:

```
# join -t, -v 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
111222,Jones,Sally
111333,Johnson,Roger
223456,Alexander,Philip
444555,Richardson,George
```

More information about the command can be found here: [man join](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join)

```
join [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2

-t CHAR
    use CHAR as input and output field separator 
-v FILENUM
    like -a FILENUM, but suppress joined output lines
```

Comment: "join" works, thanks.  However, sometimes I want to use a different field in the files.  So maybe the "awk" is better.

Comment: @pgrason Define 'fields', if there is a common field in both, join should always work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","};FNR==NR{a[$1];next};!($1 in a)' file1 file2 > file3
```

Comment: The idea is okay, but a code snippet-only answer is not.

Comment: This works the way I want.  I can chose which field to use as the key.  Thanks.  Will there be any problems with very large file1 & file2?

Comment: I just tried this command on two large .csv files and it worked just as I wanted.  Thanks!

Comment: @pgrason Is this the way you solved your problem? Then please accept the answer, so others know what worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following Python2 solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import csv
with open('file_1') as f1:
    file_1_list = [line[0] for line in csv.reader(f1)]
with open('file_2') as f2:
    for line in csv.reader(f2):
        if line[0] not in file_1_list:
            print ' '.join(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `-F','`  which tells awk that there is a comma delimiter or if you are using `|`.  use `-F'|'`

so your script should look like this now

```
awk -F',' 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};!($1 in a)' file1 file2 > file3
```